# Sending IP address or file to virus total using only bash

Tags: python, bash, security

I'm wanting to send a email to virus total containig a Chinese IP address and some malware I found on my linux system. I continually get attacked ans was curious as to how I could automate the sending process in bash.

Tried using mail command in bash to no avail.

maybe transform this python script from https://www.virustotal.com/fr/documentation/email-submissions/ to bash:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.Utils import formatdate

msg = MIMEMultipart()

mfrom = 'spam-me-not@virustotal.com'
mto = 'scan@virustotal.com'

msg['Subject'] = 'SCAN'
msg['From'] = mfrom
msg['To'] = mto
msg['Date'] = formatdate()

# Open the file to scan in binary mode
fp = open('/path/to/file', 'rb')
attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;
filename="filename"')
fp.close()
msg.attach(attachment)

# Send the email via your own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yourserver.com')
s.sendmail(mfrom, mto, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Or maybe there's a captcha free way to report a malicious IP address from command line?

Comment: why not just use python? its readily available on pretty much any system ... and this just uses builtin modules ... I dont think bash has any builtin smtp mail stuff ... and adding attachments will almost certainly require some 3rd party application

Comment: mailx has an option as -a to attach a file if that's what you are searching for. Something like, echo "Mail Body"|mailx -a 'attachmentFile' -s "Subject" dummyemail@dummydomain.com